# Does this character from "Chainsaw Man" die or is she lost?

Tags: chainsaw-man

During first season of *Chainsaw Man*

> Himeno desperately urges their contracted spirit to act against its will to fight their rivals. During this action, we see that she seems to lose first an arm, and later both, seemingly both vanished. After the fight, only her clothes remain. In the last episode of the season her contracted spirit appears again and there are subtle indications that she is somewhat linked or inside the spirit, as it gives an "easy revenge" message to Aki.

Is there any canon answer to her vanishing? Is she dead or just lost in some type of limbo?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpreview.redd.it%2Fwas-reading-fujimotos-jump-festa-interview-and-learned-that-v0-gm7u7zxn8cgb1.jpg%3Fwidth%3D1080%26crop%3Dsmart%26auto%3Dwebp%26s%3D73428cfdb8d09130b9575b2ed080c6c8ffeda47d - She ded

Answer (score 1):

#### Spoilers

She's dead.

We don't have any instances of a cost-free contract (except maybe Denji, whose contract is unclear). Himeno is apparently able to sacrifice parts of her body to power up her devil. That's all but stated the [transcript of the event](https://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?t=110363&sid=a195c21136d4779d901c93d3650b5c34) (S1E8)

> HIMENO: Ghost...
> GHOST: I refuse. That girl is scary.
> HIMENO: I will give you all of me. So let me use all of you.
> HIMENO (narrative): Aki can cry. Devil hunters get so used to death that they eventually stop crying. But Aki cries very often. When his newbies died, he'd hide away and cry. It's very interesting. It must be a really good feeling to have someone care and cry for you.

[S1E10 is more explicit](https://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?t=110365&sid=a195c21136d4779d901c93d3650b5c34) (emphasis mine)

> DENJI (narrative): Came back for my manga, but caught [Aki] crying. Of course he's crying. A bunch of his workmates died. **And his teammate Himeno is dead too...** Why do I have no tears at all? I was so sad when Pochita died. But now that it's Himeno... She was the first person to say she'd be my friend.